# Access data inside an array on a JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON that looks like this (I don't care about the info, is not anything important):

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "billing_cycle_anchor": 1611687866,
      "billing_thresholds": null,
      "cancel_at": null,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1611687866,
      "current_period_end": 1643223866,
      "current_period_start": 1611687866,
      "customer": "cus_Ipc4utw6iwpjzG",
      "days_until_due": null,
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [],
      "discount": {
        "checkout_session": null,
        "coupon": {
          "amount_off": 25,
          "created": 1611687864,
          "currency": "usd",
          "duration": "repeating",
          "duration_in_months": 3,
          "id": "eGE2X5WO",
          "livemode": false,
          "max_redemptions": 10,
          "metadata": {
            "test": "test"
          },
          "name": "25 off",
          "object": "coupon",
          "percent_off": null,
          "redeem_by": 1766448000,
          "times_redeemed": 1,
          "valid": true
        },
        "customer": "cus_Ipc4utw6iwpjzG",
        "end": 1619463866,
        "id": "di_1IDwpy2eZvKYlo2CO9NXr9NJ",
        "invoice": null,
        "invoice_item": null,
        "object": "discount",
        "promotion_code": "promo_1IDwpw2eZvKYlo2Co0OUIl0m",
        "start": 1611687866,
        "subscription": "sub_Ipc4diRpUv2E5J"
      },
      "ended_at": null,
      "id": "sub_Ipc4diRpUv2E5J",
      "invoice_customer_balance_settings": {
        "consume_applied_balance_on_void": true
      },
      "items": {
        "data": [
          {
            "billing_thresholds": null,
            "created": 1611687867,
            "id": "si_Ipc45R9qX6aYwb",
            "metadata": {},
            "object": "subscription_item",
            "plan": {
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 5,
              "amount_decimal": "5",
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1599143565,
              "currency": "usd",
              "id": "price_1HNJUX2eZvKYlo2C02FTibzq",
              "interval": "year",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {},
              "nickname": null,
              "object": "plan",
              "product": "prod_HwQjfoxyonlfag",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "price": {
              "active": true,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1599143565,
              "currency": "usd",
              "id": "price_1HNJUX2eZvKYlo2C02FTibzq",
              "livemode": false,
              "lookup_key": null,
              "metadata": {},
              "nickname": null,
              "object": "price",
              "product": "prod_HwQjfoxyonlfag",
              "recurring": {
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "interval": "year",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "trial_period_days": null,
                "usage_type": "licensed"
              },
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_quantity": null,
              "type": "recurring",
              "unit_amount": 5,
              "unit_amount_decimal": "5"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_Ipc4diRpUv2E5J",
            "tax_rates": []
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_Ipc4diRpUv2E5J"
      },
      "latest_invoice": "in_1IDwpy2eZvKYlo2ChABu4OXQ",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
      "object": "subscription",
      "pause_collection": null,
      "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
      "pending_setup_intent": null,
      "pending_update": null,
      "plan": {
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 5,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1599143565,
        "currency": "usd",
        "id": "price_1HNJUX2eZvKYlo2C02FTibzq",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_HwQjfoxyonlfag",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "schedule": null,
      "start": 1611687866,
      "start_date": 1611687866,
      "status": "active",
      "tax_percent": null,
      "transfer_data": null,
      "trial_end": null,
      "trial_start": null
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "object": "list",
  "url": "/v1/subscriptions"
}
```

So, the thing is that I'm trying to access the "id" value, inside the "data" array on the JSON doing : `jsondata.data.id` but it says the following: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'` I actually don't know where the error is, and I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: try `jsondata.data[0].id`

Comment: Oh it was that easy, sorry about my dumb question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the content of "data" is an array, we would have to access the first element of the array, so we just would have to change it to

```py
jsondata.data[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsondata.data` is a list. Iterating over it will give you the element you want.

```
for item in jsondata.data:
    print(item.id)
```